# Updating data in database using datagridview

Tags: c#, database-connection, oledb

i have a code like this:

```
public int updateFriend(long id, string Firstname, string Lastname, string Nickname, DateTime Birthdate, int Age, string Gender)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString());

        string query = "UPDATE FriendList SET Firstname  ='" + Firstname + "', Lastname ='" + Lastname + "',Nickname ='" + Nickname + "',Birthday ='" + Birthdate + "',Age ='" + Age + "', Gender  ='" + Gender + "' WHERE ID = " + id;

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();

        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return (rowsAffected);
    }
```

now the problem is when i click the update button it calls the method `updateFriend`, then an error appears on the Line `"int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`" saying

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You should use Parameterized query also look up how to use `Parameters.AddWithValue() Method` also wrap that code in a Try{}catch{} refactor the Update statement to use Params also look at string.Format to format the Update statement try to avoid using Single Quotes mixed with Double Quotes.. you will only confuse yourself in the long run..

Comment: Did you verify that all of the parameters getting passed to the query have values?

Comment: `OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString());` where is conString Declared..?

Comment: Birthdate is coming as null i think

Comment: MMK what makes you think that.?

Comment: Also make sure that you have proper spacing in your Query you probably have one or more of the fields being concatenated without the proper spacing .. but can't tell until you provide a more detailed error message

Comment: the conString is declared like this:

namespace Friends_List
{
    class FriendTrans
    {
        public String conString()
        {
            return ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=FriendsList.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        }
}
}
@DJKRAZE

Comment: missStressed .. look at the answer that `gzaxx` provided follow the same construct also doing things this way allows for the DataBase server to handle the DataType so passing in with Parameters is much safer than building the string as you did in your original attempt

Comment: oh thanks everyone... :) im gonna try it now..

Comment: It's so amazing that people still use `String.Format` or string concatenation to create SQL statements...

Answer (score 2):

```
string query = "UPDATE FriendList SET Firstname  ='" + Firstname + "', Lastname ='" + Lastname + "',Nickname ='" + Nickname + "',Birthday ='" + Birthdate + "',Age ='" + Age + "', Gender  ='" + Gender + "' WHERE ID = " + id;
```

You are passing all parameters as string where some of them are int and one is `DateTime`. As suggested you should use `Parameters.AddWithValue()`

```
string query = "UPDATE FriendList SET Firstname = @Firstname, Lastname = @Lastname , Nickname = @Nickname, Birthday = @Birthdate, Age = @Age, Gender = @Gender WHERE ID = @id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", FirstName);
//add rest parameters the same way as above
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Talking about on your *error message*;

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

This message will appears probably one of your parameters is `null` or *zero-length* string. Or the reason can be misspelling of your parameters.

Check your query in your database first and look which column gives you an error.

And please, **never** add your parameters in your sql command. That may cause [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Always use [*`parameterized query`*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) on your queries.

Check out [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method from *MSDN*.